# String Split into separate Strings in python

Tags: python

I want to split `"Onehundredthousand"` to `"one"` `"hundred"` `"thousand"` using python.
How can I do that?

Comment: post ur attempts..

Comment: Just for this particular string,there can n different solutions. But if you want  a generic solution,u need to have some delimiters.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

```
>>> s = "Onehundredthousand"
>>> s.replace('hundred', '_hundred_').split('_')
['One', 'hundred', 'thousand']
```

This will only work on the given string.

Comment: Using replace and then split? It's better to use partition.

Answer (score 6):

You can use a string's `partition` method to split it into 3 parts (left part, separator, right part):

```py
"onehundredthousand".partition("hundred")
# output: ('one', 'hundred', 'thousand')
```

Answer (score 4):

Using regular expression [`re.split`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/re.html#re.split). If you use captured group as a separator, it will be also included in the result list:

```
>>> import re
>>> re.split('(hundred)', 'Onehundredthousand')
['One', 'hundred', 'thousand']
```

Comment: Thanks for your support